# Should varnish sess_con = cache_hit + cache_hitpass + cache_miss?

Tags: varnish

My understanding of metrics from varnishstat:

> sess_con = Cumulative number of accepted client connections by Varnish
>   Cache
>
> cache_hit = Cumulative number of times a file was served from
>   Varnish’s cache
>
> cache_miss = Cumulative number of times a file was requested but was
>   not in the cache, and was therefore requested from the backend
>
> cache_hitpass = Cumulative number of hits for a “pass” file

Therefore, should sess_con = cache_hit + cache_miss + cache_hitpass?

It doesn't on my installation:

client_req    = 3053
cache_hit     =  582
cache_hitpass =    2
cache_miss    = 1940

582 + 2 + 1940 = 2524

So what happened to the (3053 - 2524) 529 other client requests?

Values for backend_fail, backend_busy and backend_unhealthy are all 0.

Answer (score 0):

If there are requests which your Varnish doesn't cache, then it is fine. But if you are caching all the requests this will be a problem